# How do you move logic from Google Sheet formula to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function `yahoofinance` which queries Yahoo!Finance for stock data based on a stock ticker. Before I can call the function, I need to do some modifications to the input.

Tickers in my sheet are of the form `[venue].[company]`, for example `XNAS.GOOG` (Google at Nasdaq), `XAMS.INGA` (ING Bank at Amsterdam) and `XSWX.CRSP` (Crispr at Swiss Exchange).

The codes that I use for the venues are international, but most API's don't use these same codes. For instance, the Amsterdam stock exchange officially is `XAMS`, but `AMS` on Google API and `AS` on Yahoo. So I have a sheet called `Exchanges` with all these venues listed. When calling my custom `yahoofinance` function, it takes the standard 'XMAS.INGA' as input, then cuts off the venue (`XAMS`) and looks up the Yahoo name (`AS`), then passes `INGA.AS` to the Yahoo API:

```
=yahoofinance(index(split(A2, "."), 0, 2) & "." & vlookup(index(split(A2, "."), 0, 1), Exchanges!E:J, 6, false))

function yahoofinance(ticker) {
  // send ticker to Yahoo API
}
```

The logic, which is now in cell `B2` in the sheet, is getting complicated to follow. I would like to move it, if possible, into the function and pass only the ticker from `A2`:

```
=yahoofinance(A2)

function yahoofinance(ticker) {
    const venue = ticker.split();
    // etc

    // end up with INGA.AS, and pass to Yahoo API
}
```

My question is: is it possible to move the logic that is now in my sheet, into the function? For example, if and how can I perform the same `vlookup` from within `yahoofinance`? Is it even possible?

I am planning to really extend the functionality of `yahoofinance`, perhaps even rework it to a generic `finance` function which also takes as argument to which API you want to pass a ticker: `=yahoofinance(ticker, api)`, so any help to get me started with a solid basis here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet so we can test out the custom formula? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this custom formula to get the modified value:

#### Script:

```
function yahoofinance(ticker) {
  var [venue, company] = ticker.split("\.");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Exchanges');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  // get Exchanges!E:J values
  var mapping = sheet.getRange(1, 5, lastRow, 6).getValues();
  // lookup equivalent, filter then get 6th column and append to company
  var modifiedTicker = company + '.' + mapping.filter(row => row[0] == venue).flat()[5];
  // you now have the modified ticker. Use it on your function.
  // ...
  return modifiedTicker;
}
```

#### B7 formula:

```
=index(split(A2, "."), 0, 2) & "." & vlookup(index(split(A2, "."), 0, 1), Exchanges!E:J, 6, false)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]